# How to access aggregate in a derived class

Tags: c++, oop, iterator, polymorphism, visitor-pattern

I know some would say it is object slicing problem but I don't think it is. I have seen many related post on this site but not quite the same. Lets begin with code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <list>

struct MY_STRUCT
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

class File
{
public:

    virtual void Load(char * fileName) = 0;
};

class ExcelFile : public File
{
protected:
    std::list<MY_STRUCT> my_list;
public:

    ExcelFile(){};
    ~ExcelFile(){};

    virtual void Load(char * fileName)
    {
        // load the file into my_list
    }
};



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char fileName[] = "test.txt";

    File * file = new ExcelFile;

    file->Load( fileName );

    // Now I need to fill a Windows List or CListView from my_list data but how?
    // I can't access or iterate my_list here and I am not too sure if
    // should pass a windows object to the class to fill it up?
    // Even if I iterate by adding a member function to return the list object, wouldn't not
    // it violate the data encapsulation rule thereby defeating the purpose of having
    // interface class?

    return 0;
}
```

So basically I have an interface class whose derived class has the data in an aggregate (collection). Now I want to display the data. What is the right way to do that? I have mentioned the problem in comments in the code...I think I have found the answer while writing this post and I should let the class add function which fills the list. And I guess if I have to fill a ListBox or ListView than I would need to two functions one for each list. I am wondering if I can do better with visitor pattern!?

Comment: just don't over protect things ! or create some sort of accessor, or have a function like Load(char* filename, list<MyStruct>* objects_in_file)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear (if I understand your question correctly) to have any worry for object splicing. It looks like all you want to do is view the list from the "aggregate" class, in this case: `ExcelFile()`

Add a method to `ExcelFile()`, maybe something like `print()`, or if you want to get fancy:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os) {
    std::list<MY_STRUCT>::iterator it;
    for (it = my_list.begin(); it != my_list.end(); ++it) {
        os << "A: " << it.a << ", B: " << it.b << std::endl;
    }

    return os;
}
```

Note: Code hasn't been compiled or run, it's just a guideline.

**EDIT**

If the OP wants to use his list elsewhere, return a constant reference to the set:

```
const std::list<MY_STRUCT> & getSet() const {
   return my_list;
}
```

Comment: Why using `std::set` here? I don't see the immediate relevance to the OP's question for doing this.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I can't read, the OP said `list` not set. Editing accordingly.

Comment: I hate I can't simply retract a downvote, I have to upvote |-< ... Though I think the getter is the most **preferable** solution, and the OP might have some misconception of that.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the OP meant by reading his/her question, so I made my best attempt at providing a solution to "want to display the  data". I know what you mean about the downvote reversal, but hey, thanks for the +10 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide at least a getter for your `my_list` member for safe access from outside the class (which wouldn't violate any encapsulation rules!):

```
class ExcelFile
{
public:
    // ...
    const std::list<MY_STRUCT>& getMyList() const { return my_list; }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This seems reasonable but when I extend on it and say use iterator design pattern to traverse the collection, it recommends to return interface class of the aggregate as well. The STL container classes does't seem to work well with general iterator design pattern although they use iterators and are considered better than them. So at the end a bit of dilemma should one use STL or own iterators/containers for complete OOP approach.

Comment: I don't agree!! `const_iterator` semantics is just fine for your use case. Or do you really need any non const access to `MY_STRUCT` from outside class methods? I wouldn't like to intern some interface to the class, that provides an interface beyond `std::ostream`!

Comment: If you look at the composite and iterator design pattern in tendom, it operates on iterator interface and iterator doesn't know what kind of container is it operating on. In this case we have to know the container type and create iterator accordingly through it like `std::list<my_struct>::iterator.

Comment: STL iterators are finally bound to their containers. So you'll need to refer from particular templated conatainers to them. (Template class/functions) Algorithms may use the `iterator` according their traits arbitrarily. Taking this track (policies), you'll need to introduce some more advanced template meta-programming for your design as you're actually showing!

Comment: Do you eventually mean `ExcelFile` itself should be a container providing an appropriate iterator?? Then there's a lot more things to do (doubt it's worth it!)?